# Get TCP/UDP Tables in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, udp

Is there a way to get a list of tcp, udp connections and processes they are associated with?

I did this in windows by using "GetExtendedTcpTable()" and "GetExtendedUdpTable()" And i want to achieve the same thing in linux.

Can someone help?

thank you.

Comment: You can try to read some [`netstat` source](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21503/source-code-of-netstat)

Comment: You can do this with SNMP.

Comment: You got help. Why don't you accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can do stuff like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream tcp("/proc/net/tcp");

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(tcp, line))
        std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

To discover what other names are available try this at the command line:

```
ls -l /proc/net/
```

Not sure the best way to associate process id (pid) with sockets but you can cross reference `/proc/<pid>/fd`, where `<pid>` is the actual number, with `/proc/net/tcp`.